# No instance of constructor error in CPP

Tags: c++

I tried to create a function to identify matched line from a string. My whole string is saved in **strStart** and **strToMatch** contains the search string. Following is my code

```
void ExpertContextUser::removeMatchedString() {
        String line;
        String strStart="Testing\nReturns\nrelated\nresources";
        String strToMatch="Test";
        istringstream streamAddtText(strStart);
        while(std::getline(streamAddtText, line)) {
                cout << line << "Function" << endl;
                if(line.index(strToMatch) > 0) {
                        TraceMessage <<" Test Success" << endl;
                }
        }
}
```

when i am compiling my code, i am getting following error

> "../user_model_impl.cxx", line 234: error #2289: no instance of constructor
>             "std::basic_istringstream<_CharT, _Traits,
>             _Allocator>::basic_istringstream [with _CharT=char,
>             _Traits=std::char_traits, _Allocator=std::allocator]"
>             matches the argument list
>               argument types are: (RWCString)
>           istringstream streamAddtText(strStart);

I am unable to find reasons for this error.

Comment: istringstream streamAddtText(strStart);, istringstream takes string as argument in constructor, not sure what is RWCString.

Comment: RWCString is a template from Rogue wave library. I changed the code to use string but still i am getting same error

Comment: What is `String` in your code?  Maybe it should be `std::string`?

Comment: It worked by using std::string. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error happens because the `istringstream` [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/basic_istringstream) takes a `std::string`, not a `RWCString`. You need to provide a conversion from `RWCString` to `std::string` if you want this to work.

Comment: I changed the code as per you suggestion, still facing same problem. I edited my question with new code and error. Thanks

Comment: @Mohan And what is `String` in your edited code then? A typedef for `std::string`? I'd guess it's still merely the same reason that your code doesn't compile.

Comment: @makulik: Yes String creates the problem. I changed it to std::string. it worked